# Bundler fails because it can't find compatible version of faraday gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, faraday

I'm trying to install a the `instagram-ruby-gem` but bundler keeps failing with this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    instagram (>= 0) ruby depends on
      faraday (< 0.9, >= 0.7.4) ruby

    instagram (>= 0) ruby depends on
      faraday (0.9.0)
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'instagram', git: 'https://github.com/larrylv/instagram-ruby-gem.git'
```

I am using this specific fork because it fixes the faraday version to be compatible with Rails 4. [See the commit here](https://github.com/larrylv/instagram-ruby-gem/commit/386ab86d11e79cda4b3fddd3139c2fb1b2bd96da), but here's the change:

```
-  s.add_runtime_dependency('faraday', ['>= 0.7', '< 0.9'])
+  s.add_runtime_dependency('faraday', '>= 0.7.4', '<= 0.9.0')
```

I already tried `bundle update`. That did not work. The only faraday version installed is `faraday 0.9.0`.

Comment: delete the `Gemfile.lock` and try to run `bundle` . may be that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the forked gem, built it and then installed it.  It looks like it went through without any issues on my end.  So it is something to do with the environment or a gem conflict issue.  I'd check to make sure you don't have any other versions of the gem installed.  Do you use RVM by any chance and use gemsets with RVM?  As a last resort you could delete the Gemfile.lock, but that is not really recommended.  You could look at the Gemfile.lock file as well and look at the faraday references.  Perhaps other gems need a certain version and the forked gem you use requires another version?  I have run in to that before.  It is not fun to try and resolve.

Mike Riley